# How can we use jQuery Expander plugin to expand/collapse according to number of lines rather than characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, expander

I have checked the following links

[jQuery expander with max-lines property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779764/jquery-expander-with-max-lines-property)

[How to get first 2 lines or 200 characters from <p> using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671621/how-to-get-first-2-lines-or-200-characters-from-p-using-jquery?lq=1)

but in these its not possible to predict the line height if your div contains headings and text of different font sizes

eg.

```
<div class='info'>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ornare cursus elementum.
Mauris et sem vitae dui vehicula lobortis a non orci. In tortor lacus, 
vehicula id placerat nec, pharetra non nunc. Aliquam id ipsum quis orci 
posuere pellentesque et vel urna. Vestibulum mattis sem ornare neque fermentum vel 
imperdiet nunc eleifend. Suspendisse potenti. Nam scelerisque sodales porttitor. Vestibulum cursus 
lobortis magna, id vehicula justo faucibus iaculis. Proin facilisis facilisis mauris. Pellentesque ultrices 
pharetra diam. Fusce a eleifend quam. Aenean eu odio dolor. Mauris augue leo, fringilla eu sagittis at, fermentum 
vitae dui. Maecenas scelerisque mi at erat posuere vitae porta metus tempor. Vivamus at ante id velit rutrum 
aliquet eget sit amet purus. Proin sed vehicula elit. Aenean a viverra nunc.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've worked some of the code in the two links you posted.  The following JSfiddle will show you how it works and what the html and css that is required is.  I suggest only using the .class for truncating on the paragraph.  This answer will account for different font sizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pjgzq/1/

Basically, once you add the jquery function in the js fiddle you need to call

```
$('.class').truncate();
```

Options can be passed in that match the "default" options in the function.

Here is the function.

```
$.fn.truncate = function(options) {
    $(this).append('<span class="truncate_lh" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>')

    var defaults = {
        maxlines: 2,
        moreText: 'More',
        lessText: 'Less',
        ellipsis: '...'
    };

    $.extend(options, {
        lineheight: ($('.truncate_lh').css('height').replace('px', ''))
    });
    $.extend(options, {
        maxheight: (options.maxlines * options.lineheight)
    });
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        var text = $(this);

        if (text.height() > options.maxheight) {

            text.css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'height': options.maxheight + 'px'
            });

            var link = $('<a href="#" class="showHide">' + options.moreText + '</a>');
            var wrapDiv = $('<div class="truncate_wrap" />');

            text.wrap(wrapDiv);
            text.after(link);

            link.click(function() {
                if (link.text() == options.moreText) {
                    link.text(options.lessText);
                    text.css('height', 'auto');
                } else {
                    link.text(options.moreText);
                    text.css('height', options.maxheight + 'px');
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for replying soon
i have updated that JSFiddle so as to give more clarification what i want
http://jsfiddle.net/Pjgzq/3/

so in this if there is some heading in the div whose line height cannot be calculated like this so it will just show that part half or something like that as in the updated jsfiddle i have placed h2 tag in the div so it doesn't work like that.

Comment: truncating multiple html elements based on two different line heights is almost impossable.  Why do you need to truncate the h2 and not the content?